# Garbled or missing LaTeX math formulas in RMarkdown->PDF knitr-converted document

Tags: r, latex, knitr, pandoc, miktex

I'm using Rstudio to write an RMarkdown document that I turn into a PDF using MiKTeX on Windows through knitr and pandoc. LaTeX engine is xelatex.

My .Rmd file YAML header:

```
---
title: "My Title"
author: "Me"
geometry: margin=2cm
output:
  pdf_document:
    fig_caption: no
    fig_height: 4
    fig_width: 6
    latex_engine: xelatex
  html_document:
    css: styles.css
    keep_md: no
fontsize: 10pt
---
```

In the text I have

```
...parameter $\lambda=0.2$ with...
```

and I get "parameter   = 0 2 with" -- both the lambda and even the dot are missing.

This line

```
mean of $\frac{1}{\lambda}=5$ of the
```

turns into

[image]

---

EDIT: When I try to add as an experiment (I'm on Windows)

```
mainfont: Arial
```

to the YAML header I get a pandoc error

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\fontspec_calc_scale:n ...ec_tmpb_dim }\fp_div:Nn 
                                                  \l_fontspec_tmpa_fp {\l_fo...
l.18     \setmainfont{Arial}

pandoc.exe: Error producing PDF from TeX source
Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 43
```

---

**UPDATE:**

Running `pdflatex report1.pdf` produces a correct PDF.

RStudio runs `"C:/Program Files/RStudio/bin/pandoc/pandoc" report1.utf8.md --to latex --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+ascii_identifiers+tex_math_single_backslash-implicit_figures --output report1.pdf --template "D:\Documents\R\win-library\3.2\rmarkdown\rmd\latex\default.tex" --highlight-style tango --latex-engine xelatex`

So it seems the elsewhere recommended engine "xelatex" produces faulty output, while "pdflatex" works. Unfortunately I forgot the reasons given by some sources incl. SO that I followed a few days ago when switching to xelatex, I only remember it was highly recommended to use that with knitr in RStudio rather than pdflatex.

Comment: it works on my computer (Linux, livetex). Could you try it step by step : first convert your Rmd to md with `knitr::knit`, then md to latex with `pandoc`, then latex to pdf with `xelatex` ?

Comment: Here is the LaTeX, looks okay: http://pastebin.com/J9LY53gS So I guess it's a MiKTeX/Windows question.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this on either Linux or Windows. I also guess it is a problem of the MikTeX installation. You did not provide the version of MikTeX (if it is not the latest version, please try to upgrade). You may also want to upgrade RStudio (http://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/preview/) and your R packages. BTW, I don't have strong arguments for using xelatex unless you work with CJK characters. For plain English documents, I don't know why pdflatex can be a bad choice.

Comment: Latest MiKTeX, I only just installed it a few days ago. I ran the package update too.

Comment: @lihang I am not sure if it exactly the same problem, but I sovled mine with: In the directory `C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64` I ran updmap.exe. After that the problem with strange looking equations was solved.

Answer (score 2):

I'm posting this answer to increase the visibility of @user1983395 's comment regarding this error.

I was facing the same error as OP. `pdflatex` just produced the mentioned error, and `xelatex` produced an error whenever there was a call to a math formula ( $X_i$ or $$X_i$$ ).

After running `C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\updmap.exe` I was able to generate a pdf both with `pdflatex` and `xelatex`. Please notice that you may need to run it as **administrator**.